# one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my database, i have two tables `notification` and `alertFrequency`. The notification has field `id and website_url` and the alert frequency has `id` and `notification_id`. Both tables has models which is one to many. The notification can have one or many `alertFrequency`.

```
class Notification extends Model {
    public function alertFrequencies() {
        return $this - > belongsToMany('AlertFrequency::class');
    }
}

namespace App;
use Illuminate\ Database\ Eloquent\ Model;
class AlertFrequency extends Model {
    protected $table = 'alertFrequencies';
    public function notification() {
        return $this - > belongsTo(Notification::class);
    }
}
```

in the notification model, i wrote a function called alert, that will give me the laastest alert associated with a specific websie.

```
public  function alert(){
    $alert_frequency = AlertFrequency::find('notification_id')->first();
    $o_notification = $this->alertFrequencies()->where('notification_id',$alert_frequency->id)
                ->select('created_at')->orderBy('created_at')->first();
    if($alert_frequency ==null){
        return false;
    }
    return created_at;
}
```

Is this a right way to extract the data? i would appreciate any suggestions and helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification hasMany AlertFrequency

```
 public function alertFrequencies(){
              return $this->hasMany('App\AlertFrequency');
        }
```

and,

```
$alert_frequency = AlertFrequency::with('notification')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
```

loads the latest `AlertFrequency` along with it's `notification`.

See [One to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in documentation.

Comment: i thought it doesn't make much difference. i will check it with it also. tnx

Comment: where should i write this code, or replace my old code.

Comment: $alert_frequency = AlertFrequency::with('notification')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

Comment: i tried your way, but i gat an error like this:::::  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notifications.alert_frequency_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notifications` where `notifications`.`alert_frequency_id` in ())

Comment: @abraham replace the relation code in model and add the query in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

to get laastest alert associated with a specific websie with url $website_url.

```
Notification::where('website_url', $website_url)->orderBy('created_at')->first();
```

hasMany relation :

```
public function alertFrequencies(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\AlertFrequency','notification_id');
    }
```